How do I make the first sentence of each headline bold, and the rest non-bold?
I'm new to emacs and orgmode.
I wonder if this is possible: if this is my headline:

Plant fence: building a fence.

Emacs should automatically show "Plant fence" bold but "building a fence" shouldn't be bold.
How is this done?
